# Hadoop running jar files probelm

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run some jar files on my hadoop installed on Windows. I can create the Jar file perfectly from the java files but every time I try to run it gives me this error:

`2023-12-04 15:02:01,966 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032 2023-12-04 15:02:03,739 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this. 2023-12-04 15:02:03,756 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/Maria/.staging/job_1701694425339_0001 2023-12-04 15:02:04,472 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1 2023-12-04 15:02:04,675 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1 2023-12-04 15:02:05,070 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1701694425339_0001 2023-12-04 15:02:05,072 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: [] 2023-12-04 15:02:05,549 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found 2023-12-04 15:02:05,551 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'. 2023-12-04 15:02:06,682 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1701694425339_0001 2023-12-04 15:02:06,829 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://DESKTOP-K5QUG8Q:8088/proxy/application_1701694425339_0001/ 2023-12-04 15:02:06,833 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1701694425339_0001 2023-12-04 15:02:14,011 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1701694425339_0001 running in uber mode : false 2023-12-04 15:02:14,018 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0% 2023-12-04 15:02:14,078 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1701694425339_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1701694425339_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1701694425339_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1 Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2023-12-04 15:02:13.720]java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: C:%5Chadoop%5Cshare%5Chadoop%5Cmapreduce%5Clib%5C* For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://DESKTOP-K5QUG8Q:8088/cluster/app/application_1701694425339_0001 Then click on links to logs of each attempt. . Failing the application. 2023-12-04 15:02:14,202 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0`

Does anyone know how this can be fixed? I really need to use hadoop for an asignment. Thank you

I was trying to run a jar file and an error occurs every time

Comment: As the logs say - `For more detailed output, check the application tracking page`